# Would you say that you are capable of being really hard?

Tags: meaning

I just heard a conversation as follows, and I don't get the meaning of "Would you say that you are capable of being really hard?" does that mean it's regarding the person should equip with strong mind?

Q:Good.  Sometimes,  though,  you may have to be very tough,  for example,  you may have to sack someone.
Would you say that you are capable of being really hard?

A: If something has to be done,  I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

*Tough* and *hard* are synonyms in this case; they mean the same thing.

To be capable to be *hard* in this case means that you are capable of taking actions that would be difficult for some people, because they would feel too emotional about it.

The hardness that is referred to is the opposite of what is often considered *weak*: thinking about other people's feelings and allowing emotions to guide your decisions.

So the question “Would you say that you are capable of being really hard?” can be rephrased as:

> Would you say that you would have a problem with firing people because you would feel sorry for them?